# How to UPDATE or Insert CTE in a table. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello Guys I having been trying to insert the result of the following code in a column called dbo.filemetadata.Source, here is the Code:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
  SELECT 
    rn, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rn ORDER BY (SELECT  NULL)) filepartno,
    Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS filepart  
  FROM  
  (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT  NULL)) rn,
     CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(FilePath, '\', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
    FROM  FileMetadata
  ) AS A 
  CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)
SELECT  FilePart AS A

FROM CTE C
  JOIN (SELECT  MAX(filepartno) maxfilepartno, rn 
        FROM CTE 
        GROUP BY rn) C2 ON C.rn = C2.rn AND C.filepartno = C2.maxfilepartno-1;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine INSERT and SELECT in CTE as with normal queries:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
 ....
)
INSERT INTO ...
SELECT  FilePart AS A

FROM CTE ....
```

*UPDATED FOR `UPDATE` Statement*

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
 ....
)
UPDATE FileMetaData 
SET SOURCE = FilePart

FROM FileMetaData INNER JOIN CTE ON ....
```

Comment: `i can insert now using  insert into FileMetadata (SourceName)
 
SELECT  FilePart 

FROM tab C
  JOIN (SELECT  MAX(filepartno) maxfilepartno, rn 
        FROM tab
        GROUP BY rn) C2 ON C.rn = C2.rn AND C.filepartno =  4  but I need the insert to match the files I have in metadata..not it is just inserting on a brand new row in file metadata.

Comment: So basically u need to UPDATE existing field in Metadata based on common values in the CTE and FileMetadata?

Comment: correct, thats what I  think I  need, I have tried couple of insert but it does not work.

Comment: it is not letting me to that, once I put my update statement, it voids the existence of my CTE.

Comment: `WITH tab AS 
(
  SELECT 
    rn, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rn ORDER BY (SELECT  NULL)) filepartno,
    Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS filepart  
  FROM  
  (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT  NULL)) rn,
     CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(FilePath, '\', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
    FROM  FileMetadata
  ) AS A 
  CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
)

SELECT  FilePart 

FROM tab C
  JOIN (SELECT  MAX(filepartno) maxfilepartno, rn 
        FROM tab
        GROUP BY rn) C2 ON C.rn = C2.rn AND C.filepartno =  4`  this is what I am trying to update

Comment: I think I am missing out something from that whole script.

Comment: It's getting overly complex, you may want to split it into several statements

Comment: The very first code is the covert an directory path into xlm, which is `WITH CTE AS 
 (  (
  SELECT 
    rn, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rn ORDER BY (SELECT  NULL)) filepartno,
    Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS filepart  
  FROM  
  (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT  NULL)) rn,
     CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(FilePath, '\', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
    FROM  FileMetadata
  ) AS A 
  CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
   ))`

Comment: now the select satement is to select the path I want from the directory which is `
 (SELECT  FilePart 

FROM CTE c
  JOIN (SELECT  MAX(filepartno) maxfilepartno, rn 
        FROM CTE
        GROUP BY rn) C2 ON C.rn = C2.rn AND C.filepartno =  9) `

Comment: now what I want is to update that selected path i.e filepart and set it = to source name. using and insert or update.

Comment: if I Put a parenthesis by it it is not letting me make use of the CTE again, OI cxan edit my code int the question with the latest update.

Comment: Yes please post the latest code update in the question, this would make things clearer

Comment: `update FileMetadata 
set SourceName = filepart
FROM CTE
inner join FileMetadata ON FilePart= (SELECT  FilePart 

FROM CTE c
  JOIN (SELECT  MAX(filepartno) maxfilepartno, rn 
        FROM CTE
        GROUP BY rn) C2 ON C.rn = C2.rn AND C.filepartno =  9)`

Comment: Does this throw an error? And again, my advice - try to untangle this into several statements

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Are u trying to update a single SourceName value or multiple? Your internal (SELECT FIlePart... returns multiple values

Comment: I am updating a sourcename multiple value